# Firefox dotted box on hoverable animation

Tags: html, css, firefox, animation

I am currently building a site that uses [animate.css](https://daneden.me/animate/) "tada" animation on some icons (see [here](http://test.themightymouth.org/)). Some users are seeing a dotted box around the div as the animation executes on a hover.  How can I remove the dotted box in Firefox?

I have tried removing it with the following CSS:

```
:focus {outline:none;}
::-moz-focus-inner {border:0;}
```

[image]

Comment: Screenshots would be a thing. Guess work probably won't lead to a solution. Let's try it anyway: `#dentisttools_icon:hover { outline: 0; }`

Comment: @kleinfreund Here is a screenshot [link](http://i.imgur.com/Mfq8IBC.jpg"). Unfortunately the outline: 0 does not work.  Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
img
{  
border-style: none;
}
```

Works for image, Ithink it will do the same for dotted boxes